# Unreachable breakpoint at execut(able/ing) code

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, c++-cli, breakpoints

I've got two DLLs, one in written in native C++ and the other in C++/CLI. The former is injected into a process, and at a later point in time, loads the latter. While debugging, I noticed that the native DLL's breakpoints were functioning correctly while the other's weren't, even though its code was being executed.

The breakpoints showed this message: *This breakpoint will not be hit. No executable code associated with this line. Possible causes include: preprocessor directives or compiler/linker optimizations.*

The modules window tells me that the plugin's symbols are loaded. I'm running with its DEBUG build. Any ideas on why this is so and perhaps a fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for what you faced is that the PDBs ("PDB stands for Program Database, a proprietary file format (developed by Microsoft) for storing debugging information about a program) are not up-to-date.

Try to clean the solution (that contains the managed code DLL) and rebuild it again.

**Tip**: if you are referring to the DLL, try to put the up-to-date pdbs beside the it. You can get the pdbs from your bin folder.

Comment: The issue persists even after cleaning and rebuilding the DLL.

Comment: Are you sure the latest pdbs exists in the same path as the dll you are referencing?

Comment: Yes, I manually copied it from the build directory after compilation.

Comment: Have you try to add a 'Debugger.Break();' explicitly in your dll and run your code normally to see whether you will be prompted to attach a debugger at this point or not?

Comment: Tried that during an earlier session, but did get the prompt. In retrospect, I think that was probably due to the fact that I was already debugging it. I'll try again and see if it works.

EDIT: It does. You have my thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Visual Studio. Do you have mixed-mode debugging switched on?

(Project Properties->Debugging->Debugger Type)

Comment: I had the property set to Auto. Changing it to Mixed, or Managed only for that matter, didn't produce any results.