# possible causes include preprocessor directives or compiler linker optimizations,vs10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I bumped into the following issue while trying to achieve breakpoint in the class method.

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line. Possible causes include: preprocessor directive or compiler/linker optimization

In another methods of this class breakpoints could be inserted.
This function is reffered in the code.If I don't put breakpoint and just want to step into it ,from the place in the code ,where it is called I get NULL pointer assertion.
The class is implemented in `*.hpp` file.
I tried to clean and re-build ,but it didn`t help.
Any advices/thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unreachable breakpoint at execut(able/ing) code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495262/unreachable-breakpoint-at-executable-ing-code)

Comment: This code could be in a plugin/dll that has not been loaded yet.

Comment: @Roddy - It is not duplication.The answers supported there didn`t help.And the case id different since another methods from this class are executed successfuly

Comment: Somebody down-voted this question. I would like to know the reason.. what are you missing guys?

Comment: It could be anything. Without any code shown, it's impossible to tell. And the "question title" is a very poor choice. How about "Why won't VS10 let me set a breakpoint?"

Comment: @dsign - well, can *you* provide any helpful response given the question as it stands? I can't. (I'm not the downvoter, BTW)

Comment: @Roddy - No I can't. But if I used VS or were any closer to be of some help, I would have asked for particular details that could help to figure it out.... oh, but I have a hint, now that come to think about it...

Comment: @Yakov - Here is my advice: ditch the debugger and use old good " cout << .... ". Breakpoints are great, but only when they work. And they always have plenty of reasons to not work.